# Error when trying to publish book using bookdown::publish_book() in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown

I would like to publish a bookdown project to bookdown.org from inside RStudio using `bookdown::publish_book()` via rsconnect. When I call `bookdown::publish_book(render = 'local')` the following error occurs and puzzles me:

```
Preparing to deploy site...Error: HTTP 400
POST https://bookdown.org/__api__/applications
Application name must be between 3 and 64 alphanumeric characters, 
dashes, and underscores.
```

Does anyone have a hint where this error might come from?

Comment: Your book folder's name may be too long or contain special characters. Check `basename(getwd())`.

Comment: Thank you! The basename was okay but I overlooked that `book_filename` had spaces. The saga continues: now I get `HTTP 409
POST https://bookdown.org/__api__/applications
An object with that name already exists.` But nothing is listed under "published content" in my profile at bookdown/rsconnect...

Comment: I can probably delete it on the server. Could you email me your username? (Or if you don't mind sharing it publicly, you can tell me here)

Comment: That would be great, thank you! my username is martin.arnold. I made several attempts to publish the book using different paths/directory names, you may delete everything.

Comment: Okay. Deleted. Could you retry?

Comment: I did. Now it is `Vanity URL may include only alphanumeric characters, hyphens, underscores, and slashes.`

Comment: Then I don't know what to do. I've deleted it on bookdown.org again. Perhaps you can try to delete your `rsconnect` folder, rebuild the book, and run `bookdown::publish_book()` again (without `render = 'local'`).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Tried that but still not working (`Vanity URL [...]`). Strange.

Comment: Yeah, it is indeed odd. I just tried to publish a book by myself, and I didn't have this problem.

Comment: I've created a new project and tried to publish the (completely untouched) minimal example. Same error. Reinstalling RStudio and R didn't help either. I'll try it again on another machine later...

Comment: I finally managed to upload my book. I had to register to rsconnect with another gmail account. Still no idea what‘s wrong with my primary account though. Thanks again for taking time Yihui!

Comment: Okay. Good to know at least you have got one working account!